# Run code 5 times in parallel

Tags: c#, multithreading

Well I thought this worked, but it seems to queue them up in order instead of running them all in parallel...  The goal is to multithread the DoWork code and execute all the batches at the same time

```
    public void RunCommands(int runid, int batchid)
    {            
        this.FillList(runid, batchid);
        int total = this.sitecollection.Count();
        if (total >= 1500)
        {
            int[][] batches = this.CreateBatch(total);
            Parallel.Invoke(() =>
            {
                this.DoWork(batches[0][0], batches[0][1], runid, batchid);
                this.DoWork(batches[1][0], batches[1][1], runid, batchid);
                this.DoWork(batches[2][0], batches[2][1], runid, batchid);
                this.DoWork(batches[3][0], batches[3][1], runid, batchid);
                this.DoWork(batches[4][0], batches[4][1], runid, batchid);
            }
            );
        }

    }
    public delegate void AsyncThreads(int batchstart, int batchend, int runid, int batchid);

    public void DoWork(int batchstart, int batchend, int runid, int batchid)
    {
      //do some work
    }
```

Comment: Per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460705(v=vs.110).aspx) 'Parallel.Invoke()' does not guarantee that the tasks will run concurrently. The runtime will schedule the tasks to scale to the number of cores on your machine.

Comment: @PatHensel: That isn't the problem. This code guarantees the work is done sequentially.

Comment: @david.pfx You are correct. I missed that when I first read the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the syntax you're looking for:

```
public void RunCommands(int runid, int batchid)
{            
    this.FillList(runid, batchid);
    int total = this.sitecollection.Count();
    if (total >= 1500)
    {
        int[][] batches = this.CreateBatch(total);

        Parallel.Invoke(
            () => { this.DoWork(batches[0][0], batches[0][1], runid, batchid); },
            () => { this.DoWork(batches[1][0], batches[1][1], runid, batchid); },
            () => { this.DoWork(batches[2][0], batches[2][1], runid, batchid); },
            () => { this.DoWork(batches[3][0], batches[3][1], runid, batchid); },
            () => { this.DoWork(batches[4][0], batches[4][1], runid, batchid); }
        );
    }

}
public delegate void AsyncThreads(int batchstart, int batchend, int runid, int batchid);

public void DoWork(int batchstart, int batchend, int runid, int batchid)
{
  //do some work
}
```

`Parallel.Invoke` accepts a `params Action[]` argument.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992634(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: How does one accomplish this similar task above but dynamically create threads or parallel tasks?  what happens is this program is passed a huge list of urls and based off that master list the app get different start and end points in that list identified by batches[][].. I want to spin up like 800 threads instead, but typing them all out would be insane, how can I do this?

Comment: @GarinKartes, you probably wouldn't use Parallel.Invoke for that. You can transform any IEnumerable for parallel execution using the "AsParallel" extension method. Give it a look: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd413237(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Well I have made quite a bit of progress.  Now the first thread to spawn gets all the resources while the other threads kind of wait.  The other threads do fire once in a while, but nowhere near the speed of the first thread.  Why does only the first thread go so fast?

```
    public void RunCommands(int runid, int batchCount)
    {            
        Task[] tasks = new Task[batchCount];
        maxBatch = batchCount;

        for (int i = 0; i < batchCount; i++ )
        {
            if (i != batchCount && i >= 0)
            {
                tasks[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(runid, i));
                Thread.Sleep(500);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Overflow..");
            }
        }
        Task.WaitAll(tasks);
    }
```